# Shortcut Eclipse open declaration type

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I know there is `open declaration` shortcut `F3`  but is there also a shortcut or possibility to set it for `open declaration type` action? I searched key preferences but could not find it? Is there any trick to open it using just keyboard ?

Comment: Which of the many languages supported by Eclipse are you asking about?

Comment: The question is about Java code

Comment: just hold down control and hover over an object or anything at it will open its declaration

Answer (score 0):

Assign a key stroke for `Navigate -> Open Hyperlink` command via `Preferences -> Keys`.

Now you can use this key stroke instead of using `Ctrl+Click` to bring up the hyperlink popup (in my case I use F6 than arrow down to `Open Declared Type`)

Not exactly what you are looking for, but this is the way to minimize mouse use.